# Oracle SQL check correlative ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, range

I have the classic table with ranges:

```
Range1 - 1 - 3.99
Range2 - 4 - 6.99
Range3 - 7 - 10
```

Is there any well-known SQL, built-in Oracle function, anything... to check they are correlative, adjacent or next one after other?

In the example above, validation is true.
So, `3.99 + 0.01 = 4`, and it's right

If the end of `Range1` was `3.72` or the beggining of `range2` was `4.12`, that was wrong.
Irrational numbers like Pi or values with more than two decimals are not allowed.

Thank you. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your ranges don't overlap, you could use the LAG() windowing function:

```
with v_data as (
  select 'Range1' name, 1 low, 3.99 high from dual union all
  select 'Range2' name, 4 low, 6.99 high from dual union all
  select 'Range3' name, 7 low, 10 high from dual 
) 
select 
  v1.*,
  lag(high) over (partition by 1 order by high) as prev_high ,
  low - lag(high) over (partition by 1 order by high) as diff 
from v_data v1
```

This will return the difference to the previous range in the "diff" column; if you put this inside another query and filter by diff > 0.01, this will return 0 rows if your ranges are close enough.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have tested your query in SQLFiddle and it works perfectly, that's what I need.

Comment: @realspirituals , yes, it seems. In SQL Fiddle I tested it with Range1 from 1 to 7.99 , and "diff" column contains values different from 0.01 (reference right value).

Answer (score 1):

Given that in a valid data set one component of each range is defined to be correct only on the basis of its comparison to another value in the set, it has redundant data elements.

You could more robustly define the data set by specifying only the lower or upper boundary values, and avoid the possibility of invalid data.

For the purposes of display you could reconstruct the ranges easily, using the Lag() or Lead() windowing function.

Comment: thank you for your answer. LAG funcion will save me some work.